# Redux Provider stucks even followed thoroughly the docs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

redux/store.js

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from './slices/userSlice' 
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer, 
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  version: 1,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({ serializableCheck: false }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

main.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import { store, persistor } from './redux/store.js'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </PersistGate>,
)
```

```
Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useMemo')
```

I had tried numerous times to add the redux store to the app by following the format thoroughly and took reference on other projects. I do not know why the error occurred unexpectedly even I really followed the correct format of redux store.

I followed thoroughly the docs and the error occurred unexpectedly.

Comment: You didn't follow the documentation though. [The documentation specifies that the `ProviderGate` component should be a child of the `Provider` component](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist?tab=readme-ov-file#basic-usage), not the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Redux-Persist `PersistGate` should be a descendent of the Redux `Provider` component that provides the `store` instance. Swap the order of the `PersistGate` and the `Provider` components.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import App from './App.jsx';
import './index.css';
import { store, persistor } from './redux/store.js';

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
      <App />
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
)
```

You'll want to also not ***indiscriminately*** disable the serializability middleware. See [Using with Redux-Persist](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist) for details. You just want to ignore the non-serializable Redux-Persist actions (*and any other non-serializable actions if they exists*).

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist'
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import userReducer from './slices/userSlice';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userReducer, 
});

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  version: 1,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const ignoredActions = [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER];

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions
      }
    }),
});

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```