# A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `register`. Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-persist

The console is indicating this error:*A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `register`. Value: ƒ register(key) {
*pStore.dispatch({
type: *constants__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0**.REGISTER,
key: key
});
}
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  {type: 'persist/PERSIST', register: ƒ, rehydrate: ƒ}
**reduxPersist.JS**

```
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';

export default (reducers) => {
  const persistedReducers = persistReducer(
    {
      key: 'REACT-BASE',
      storage,
      whitelist: ['exempleReducer'],
    },
    reducers
  );

  return persistedReducers;
};
```

**index.js**

```
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from './modules/rootReducer';
import rootSaga from './modules/rootSaga';

import persistedReducers from './modules/reduxPersist';

const persistedReducer = persistedReducers(rootReducer);
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(sagaMiddleware),
});

sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);

export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export default store;
```

Comment: ***Lots*** of answers in the marked duplicate, many of which IMHO incorrectly suggest to completely disable the serializability middleware, but my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77923572/8690857) to an unrelated question also exactly addresses the serializability issue with Redux-Persist that you face.